# SimpleDateFormat.parse()

Tags: java

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` accepts the date `003/1/2011` when the format is `MM/dd/yyyy`. Trying with code below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date dt2;
try
{
    dt2 = sdf.parse(_datemmddyyyy);
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    return false;
}
```

and the date is parsed as `00/11/2011`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure? This:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date dt2 = sdf.parse("003/1/2011");
System.out.println(dt2);
```

Yields:

```
Tue Mar 01 00:00:00 PST 2011
```

That's `03/01/2001` in `MM/dd/yyyy`. Seems right?

Comment: I get the same result: `Tue Mar 01 00:00:00 CET 2011`

Comment: Going a step further, `sdf.format(sdf.parse("003/1/2011"))` returns `03/01/2011`.